# Amazon Elastic Transcoder Fails With Files Larger than 100mb

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I have a social media website, and I think it will attract a lot of visitors. It allows users to upload images and video. For video, it uploads with PHP then converts it to the right format using Elastic Transcoder. It then stores the files into S3 Buckets. When I upload small videos (less than around 80mb) it works fine. But if I upload like a 150 or 300mb file, the job fails. Can anyone tell me why it happens and how to fix this? I have been stuck on this for the past 2 months.

Comment: what 'fails' upload?, transcodeing? storing?

Comment: it uploads, but doesn't transcode successfully

Comment: This sounds like a question for the [Amazon Transcoder forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=147) or perhaps [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/support), not one that can be solved on Stack Overflow.

Comment: sure, I'll ask there too

Comment: Did you got the answer? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a few issues;

1. Your PHP script is timing out, do you need to set a higher time out limit for that script?
2. Max POST size is too small, you may need to edit the PHP config to increase POST OR Memory limits.

Also you should check the PHP and Apache logs to see if anything odd is occurring.

Comment: sorry, neither of those is it. I forgot to mention, it uploads the uploaded file to an S3 bucket first and elastic transcoder pulls it from there. I can see it in the s3 bucket